# Respond_with templates and status codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, respond-with

There are some instances where I need to both have a template and return error codes when using respond_with in Rails 3.

I have a before filter that is as follows:

```
def ensure_premium
  respond_with("Must be a premium user!", status: 401, location: nil) unless current_user.is_premium?
end
```

and a create action that does the following:

```
def create
    @wait_list = @hangout.wait_lists.find_or_create_by(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_with(@wait_list) do |format|
      format.json {render 'create', status: 201}
    end
end
```

Even though the before filter trips, it still tries to render the template which results in an error. What am I missing to get it to return the right error and status code and not render the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going a different route completely so this question is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple respond_with's for the create action. But I think more critically, you might need:

```
def ensure_premium
  respond_with :json => {:error => "Must be a premium user!", :status => :unauthorized } unless....
```

I don't think this is the problem, but make sure in your controller you have

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
```

Comment: I do have respond_to :json in the controller, but I will try your suggestion today to see if it helps.

Comment: That ended up not helping, unfortunately. It still tries to render the template